# How to adapt animation in AJAX response message?

Tags: jquery, ajax

The execution works very well, the errors are shown in the animation disappear by **[x]** seconds and you have the possibility to close the message that ajax emits.

The problem that I present is that the animation remains active and should not remain active, the message should only be displayed when it receives or emits an ajax message.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".dismiss").click(function() {
    $(".result").fadeOut(500);
  });

  $(document).on('submit', '#code', function() {

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'code_ticket.ini.php',
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $(".result").fadeIn(200);
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $(".result").html(response);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          $('.result').fadeOut(500);
        }, 6000);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.result {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"><span class="dismiss">X</span></div>
```

Comment: I am trying to understand that which part of the code you are referring to when you say animation, whereas there is no `animate()` call in your code are you talking about the `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam if to that, excuse me if I understand it badly, but as it is called something that appears and disappears?

Comment: so you are trying to say that the **[x]** always is there no matter if you havent sent an ajax call ? and you want it to appear along with the message not before ? Correct?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes so friend, as you say :)

Comment: i posted an answer please review it. @gPH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly the **[x]** appears before the ajax response is received, and you want it to appear exactly when the response is received, then you have to remove the `beforeSend` from your ajax call and move the line

`$(".result").fadeIn(200);`

inside the `success` function after the line

`$(".result").html(response);`

your final script will look like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".dismiss").click(function () {
            $(".result").fadeOut(500);
        });

        $(document).on('submit', '#code', function () {

            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'code_ticket.ini.php',
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    $(".result").html(response);
                    $(".result").fadeIn(200);
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.result').fadeOut(500);
                    }, 6000);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
```

**EDIT**

Additionally, you have to add a message span inside your `result` container with class `message` change your `result` `div` like below.

```
<div class="result">
    <span class="dismiss">X</span>
    <span class="message"></span>
</div>
```

and change the line

`$(".result").html(response);`

to

`$(".result>span.message").html(response);`

and you are all done

Comment: It's weird the [x] is still there, I think you have to apply a `display: none;` to the message container and when the message is received a `display: block;`

Comment: can you provide the html for that section so i could check at my end, and `display: none;` is already added to the parent class `.result` no need to set it again, add the html section for the `.result` div or container that you have better add in the Original post

Comment: or if you have a live link that would do it

Comment: If you have to add what I mention, because if I give styles to the container `.result` for example a background color, the container is there without having had ajax response

Comment: The code is  original friend, unfortunately I do not have it live

Comment: how is that possible? I have replicated the same code on my local system and whatever color I give to the background for `.result` it never shows up by default because `display:none` is already given in your class for `css`

Comment: But it does not show the [x] when I receive a response from ajax, it apparently removes content from the container and only shows what ajax emits.

Comment: i just updated the answer see the **EDIT** part and follow the instructions all will work fine @gPH

Comment: analyze the code with the developer tool, observe friend [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKzc1.png)

Comment: yeah i got it see the updated answer and follow instructions, it will fix